# Heroku ephemeral storage, Sendgrid, and attachments

Tags: django, heroku, email-attachments, sendgrid

On occasion I need to send emails with attachments to users of my site.  I am using SendGrid and [python-sendgrid 0.1.4](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-python) to do the send.  Email sending is queued through Redis.

Here's the issue -- where do I put the attachment, which is currently generated as part of the web process?  I tried putting it /tmp, which didn't work -- presumably because the file was deleted when the web process shut down and was no longer available when the worker process came by?  I tried /app/media, which also didn't work -- I think because /app/media is read-only (though, oddly, I did not get any errors attempting to write to this directory)?

I think the answer may be that I have to refactor my code to generate the attachment in the same process as the email is sent, but as that is a pretty significant refactor, I thought I'd ask the community first.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heroku's `/tmp` directories are [unique to each dyno](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). So your Web Dyno saves a file in its `/tmp` directory, then your worker looks in *its* `/tmp` directory and cannot find it.

The best option is likely refactoring your code (that way you aren't clogging up your Web Dyno's resources creating and writing files to disk). However, if you really want to avoid it, you could store your files temporarily on S3 [[tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3)] or some other external storage mechanism.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I used S3 for all the static assets.  I had just sorta hoped to avoid the network overhead here... not to mention the refactoring.  But it seems like it will be necessary one way or the other.  Sigh.  Thanks!

Comment: If you are really concerned about the network overhead, I would encourage you to check out the article on [client side direct uploads to S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python).

Answer (score 2):

You always need to use an external storage like for example S3, to store files that need to be available to every server instance/dyno.
Interesting to know is, if you don't want to store those attachements forever. You can attach a lifecycle event to your S3 bucket that will automatically delete a file if it's older then x days.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I handle the S3 assets and expiring old versions of JS/CSS files.  Had hoped to avoid the network overhead here, but I guess it's unavoidable.  Thanks for the advice.